# Porting a win32 application to Win CE

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, winapi, windows-ce

I have a win32 GUI (MFC) application which I need to port to a WIN CE environment. I keep encountering undefined identifiers. What is the best way to deal with this- is there some site where i can get a mapping of some kind between win32 supported features and corresponding wince features (even if they are not supported, the information that they are not is valuable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:
[MFC Reference for Devices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s054yys1.aspx)